# How to create tag fileds in iOS

Tags: ios, tags

How can I create a tag fields like the below attached screenshot in iOS.

[image]

tag text shall be taken from the user input.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3 Xcode 8.3.2**

Its easy. No need to use any framework for this, You can create your own view.

Suppose you have a ViewController on which you want to add skills for particular user. So on that view you will be having one TextField to accept the skill name and a collectionView to show all the skills entered by the user.Check image for more clear view.

[image]

Create skills array which you need to pass to your collectionView delegate methods.

```
var skillArray = [String]()
```

Now whenever you add anything inside your textfield and on press of return button on keyboard you need to add that skill name in your skills array and reload your collectionView.

```
skillArray.append(textField.text)

collectionView.reloadData()
```

Next add collectionview methods:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.skillArray.count
}

// make a cell for each cell index path
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let skillCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "collectionViewCell", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! SkillCollectionViewCell
    skillCell.skillLabel.text = skillArray[indexPath.row]
    skillCell.deleteAction = {
        self.skillArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        self.collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    return skillCell
}
```

Final step is to add collectionViewFlowLayout methods.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
                // handle tap events
                print("You selected cell #\(indexPath.item)!")

            }

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGSize{
                let widthText = self.skillArray[indexPath.item]

                let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:18)
                let fontAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font] // it says name, but a UIFont works
                let myText = widthText
                let size = (myText as NSString).size(attributes: fontAttributes)

                return CGSize(width: size.width+28, height:30)
            }
```

Comment: Hi @Prashant Gaikwad. I am trying your approach. But my tags are not starting from left position and spacing between tags is random. Can you please help me out with his

Comment: If I understand you well, you are saying that your tags view is ready it's just that it is not starting from the very left side of the collection view. In this case, make sure you are setting the left spacing of each cell to 0. You can do this from a storyboard or programmatically using collectionview's flowlayout delegate.

Answer (score 0):

You can use more Designs with using user input and handling the `tag` by using `cell` `index` of `collection` `view` for more designs follow the link -

https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=flowlayout

Answer (score 0):

I recommend UICollectionView to implement Tags. It's less code, less overhead and easy to implement.

Follow this link for guidance :

https://codentrick.com/create-a-tag-flow-layout-with-uicollectionview/

This is how it looks like. Please note it is flexible too.

[image]

Hope this will help you

Comment: that link, while well meaning, doesn't really work at all when the strings get long